# com/apple/transporter/osgi/FelixOSGiBootstrapper : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: ios, ionic3

When trying to upload the application to the app store I get the following error

com/apple/transporter/osgi/FelixOSGiBootstrapper : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Needs to add more details to get clear picture on your app upload.